# backbone model cannot fetch any data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Here're my simplified codes

```
var PlayerModel = Backbone.Model.extend();

var PlayerProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({
model : new PlayerModel({url: "http://mysite.com/api/getpalyer.php"}),
render: function(){
this.model.fetch();
}
});
```

the system keeps giving me this error message

> Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified

I totally have no idea what's wrong with my code.

Comment: You have defined a `PlayerModel` not a `Player`, is that just a typo in your example?

Comment: it's a typo in the question... but it's PlayerModel in my code

Comment: Replace the semicolon in the end `new PlayerModel({url: "http://mysite.com/api/getpalyer.php"});` with comma as `new PlayerModel({url: "http://mysite.com/api/getpalyer.php"}),`

Comment: it's a comma already in my code... there's just a typo in my question

Answer (score 3):

Here's the `Backbone#Model`'s constructor:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
```

So as you see, the `options` should be given as the second argument. Here you're passing your url as an `attribute` (try `this.get('url')` to verify that).

Change it to:

```
model : new PlayerModel(null, {url: "http://mysite.com/api/getpalyer.php"});
```

**Another thing:**

Also, declaring a new object in the class definition (`new PlayerModel({url: "http://mysite.com/api/getpalyer.php"}),`) will result in having a single instance of this object shared by all your objects (ie any `PlayerProfileView` will share a single instance of `PlayerModel`). The reason behind it is that it's evaluated when the class is created and put in the prototype of your class.

Comment: there's no warning now.... but nothing is got either.
I used get('url') to check if the url is correct.... it tells me it's undefined... so weird

Comment: and i also used toJSON to check what is inside the model.... there's nothing in it... but I am very sure the url works properly and return a json

Comment: @ChitoCheng `get('url')` will work in the wrong version (the one you pass the url as an attribute). Use `this.url` to check it in the right version. As for the request itself, check your network tab in the console, it'll help.

Comment: i have solved the problem by simple pass a {async: false} option to the .fetch() function. and everything is working fine now.

Comment: @ChitoCheng you shouldn't do that if you can avoid it, you're losing the interest of making asynchronous calls. If this solved your problem of not having anything in your model, it's just that you were checking what was inside before the data arrived. Try `myModel.fetch({success: function() {console.log(this)});` to check what is really inside your model after you fetched it. Oh, and consider accepting the answer since it was the solution to the problem you posted.

Comment: thanks for you answer... will try your method in my next project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put `url` in the definition of `PlayerModel` instead of passing it when you call `new`. If you still want to pass it in `new`, you need to specify it as the second param (as `Loamhoof` pointed out)

```
var PlayerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: "http://mysite.com/api/getpalyer.php"
});
```

Comment: there's no warning now... but nothing is fetched... I used toJSON to check what is inside the model... but it's empty. and even I used get('url'), it returns me 'undefined'